# jQuery expand collapsible list view on filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have several collapsed listviews. These can be filtered by an input field. At the moment, they're all collapsed and need to be opened individually after filtering. I'd like filtering to open them automatically. My question is very similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172248/automatically-open-filtered-collapsible-set-items-jquery-mobile), but specifically I'm filtering a collapsible listview widget, not a collapsible widget. Any help would be much appreciated!

html:

```
    <form class="ui-filterable">
        <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search">
    </form>
    <div class="filterMe" data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" and data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h2>Foods</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Fruits</li>
            <li><a href="#"">Apple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Orange</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Banana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Grapes</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Vegies</li>
            <li><a href="#"">Carrot</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Lettuce</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Pumpkin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Celery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="filterMe" data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" and data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h2>Things</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Kitchen things</li>
            <li><a href="#"">Plates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Bowls</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Cutlery</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Office things</li>
            <li><a href="#"">Pens</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Paper</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"">Computer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#usagePicker", function () {
    $(".filterMe").on("filterablefilter", function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-collapsible:not(.ui-screen-hidden)").collapsible("option", "collapsed", false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check if any listview items are visible after the filter and then expand/collapse based on that:

```
$(".filterMe").on("filterablefilter", function (event, ui) {
    var anyVisible = false;
    ui.items.each(function( index ) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-screen-hidden")){
            anyVisible = true;
        }
    });
    $(this).collapsible("option", "collapsed", !anyVisible);
});
```

## **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/vXYjXB)**

Comment: Thanks ezanker, but this didn't work for me. I even tried changing it to `$(".filterMe").on("filterablefilter", function (event, ui) {alert("triggered");});` but that's not working, so I'm not sure why it's not even being triggered. To complete the picture - the list that I'm filtering is brought in via an ajax call (but would that make a difference??). As you can see there are 2 collapsible sets (though there could be more) which are BOTH filtered concurrently by an external input field - perhaps that might impact things? What do you think?

Comment: @Brad, after the ajax call you should call filterable("refresh") http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#method-refresh  Also, the filterablefilter handler should be defined within the pagecreate.

Comment: Thanks @ezanker. I tried both of those things with no luck unfortunately. I added the following code to my ajax caller (which is within documentReady): `$('#family').change(function() {
  myFamily = $(this).val();
  $("#ajaxDiv").load( "functions.php", { "changeFamilyGroup": "true", "Family": myFamily }, function() {
   $(this).enhanceWithin();
  });
  $(".filterMe").filterable("refresh");
 });`
 and I added `$(".filterMe").on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {
 $(this).on("filterablefilter", function (event, ui) {alert("triggered");});
});` just within <script> tags but no luck!

Comment: (also, the #family selector is not shown in my initial post, its just a select box which loads the appropriate ul lists in my original question)

Comment: it is not $(".filterMe").on( "pagecreate", but $(document).on("pagecreate","#yourpageid", function(){...  See my codepen demo.  Youcould also try putting your AJAX call witin the pagecreate instead of document ready.

Comment: Thanks again @Ezanker, but that still doesn't seem to do the trick. It doesn't look like your codeine demo is working properly either. At this point, all I'm looking to do is execute an alert after a filter! Should be easy right?

Comment: Looks like @OYORF you had the same issue as me. How did you solve it?

Comment: Got it working! I called `$( ".filterable" ).on( "filterablefilter", function( event, ui ) { alert("Text"); });` within `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){` and it's firing! Now to get back to my original problem of making them open after filtering. When I have it working I'll post a solution here!